# Storing multiple values for keys in KyotoDB

Tags: hash, indexing, tokyo-cabinet, kyotocabinet

Could you please let me know if one can store multiple values for same key/s in Kyoto Cabinet(KB). I need to implement a quick indexing mechanism for a large chunk of data which could have multiple values for same keys and I am trying to test KB for it.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Answer (score 1):

seems like that **kyotocabinet** does not have support for multiple values for the same key. 
[the blog entry](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/13/tokyo-cabinet-beyond-key-value-store/) is about **tokyocabinet**, which is a similar yet different key-value storage made by fallabs.

there is, however, a workaround with append() method, which adds data to the end of the stored value. which can be quite convenient if you have fixed-sized values.

Comment: No dude. Check this http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/javadoc/.. Putup method. I am using that.

Comment: this is TOKYO cabinet, dude :)

Answer (score 0):

I have very less idea about Kyoto Cabinet. Just start to play with it. I also require what you want for my coding. And what resources I found about it is following:

[blog](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/13/tokyo-cabinet-beyond-key-value-store/) And this blog says: your answer is YES, you can store multiple values for same key/s using B Tree DB Engine.

Note: I have not tested it, just trying to help you by providing what info I have.

Comment: @Abhi, I check that. Putup method of BTree allows key-multiple values. More info: No dude. Check this http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/javadoc/.. Putup method. I am using that.